# UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xff in position 0: invalid start byte in django

Tags: python, django

I want to get the list of posts api through the get request.But after writing the code, I sent the get request and the following error appears.

Traceback

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\kurak\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\kurak\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 145, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "C:\Users\kurak\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 143, in _get_response
    response = response.render()
  File "C:\Users\kurak\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\template\response.py", line 105, in render
    self.content = self.rendered_content
  File "C:\Users\kurak\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\response.py", line 70, in rendered_content
    ret = renderer.render(self.data, accepted_media_type, context)
  File "C:\Users\kurak\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\renderers.py", line 100, in render
    ret = json.dumps(
  File "C:\Users\kurak\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\utils\json.py", line 25, in dumps
    return json.dumps(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\kurak\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\json\__init__.py", line 234, in dumps
    return cls(
  File "C:\Users\kurak\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\json\encoder.py", line 199, in encode
    chunks = self.iterencode(o, _one_shot=True)
  File "C:\Users\kurak\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\json\encoder.py", line 257, in iterencode
    return _iterencode(o, 0)
  File "C:\Users\kurak\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\utils\encoders.py", line 50, in default
    return obj.decode()
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xff in position 0: invalid start byte
```

In the previous code, we received it normally without any decoding errors, and this problem occurs after modification. What's the problem? Here's my code.

views.py

```
class CreateReadPostView (ModelViewSet) :
    serializer_class = PostSerializer
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]
    queryset = Post.objects.all()

    def perform_create (self, serializer) :
        serializer.save(author=self.request.user)

    def list (self, request) :
        posts = Post.objects.all()
        data = []

        for post in posts :
            comments = Comment.objects.filter(post=post)

            json = {
                'pk': post.pk,
                'author': {
                    'email': post.author.email,
                    'username': post.author.username,
                    'profile': post.author.profile
                },
                'like': post.liker.count, 
                'liker': post.liker,
                'text': post.text,
                'images': Image.objects.filter(post=post),
                'comments_count': comments.count(),
                'view': post.view,
                'viewer_liked': None,
                'tag': post.tag
            }
            data.append(json)

        return Response(data, status=200)
```

serializers.py

```
class ImageSerializer (serializers.ModelSerializer) :
    image = serializers.ImageField(allow_null=True, use_url=True)

    class Meta :
        model = Image
        fields = ['image']

class PostSerializer (serializers.ModelSerializer) :
    author = serializers.CharField(source='author.username', read_only=True)
    title = serializers.CharField(allow_null=True)
    text = serializers.CharField(allow_null=True)
    image = ImageSerializer(many=True, allow_null=True, read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = ['pk', 'author', 'title', 'text', 'like', 'liker', 'image', 'view']

    def validate (self, attrs) :
        title = attrs.get('title', '')
        text = attrs.get('text', '')
        image = attrs.get('image', '')

        error = {}

        if title is None and text is None and image is None :
            error['message'] = '제목, 본문, 그리고 이미지를 넣어주세요.'
            raise serializers.ValidationError(error)

        if title is None and text is None :
            error['message'] = '제목과 본문을 넣어주세요.'
            raise serializers.ValidationError(error)

        if title is None and image is None :
            error['message'] = '제목과 이미지를 넣어주세요.'
            raise serializers.ValidationError(error)

        if text is None and image is None :
            error['message'] = '본문과 이미지를 넣어주세요.'
            raise serializers.ValidationError(error)

        if title is None  :
            error['message'] = '제목을 넣어주세요.'
            raise serializers.ValidationError(error)

        if text is None :
            error['message'] = '본문을 넣어주세요.'
            raise serializers.ValidationError(error)

        if image is None :
            error['message'] = '이미지를 넣어주세요.'
            raise serializers.ValidationError(error)

        return attrs

    def create (self, validated_data) :
        images_data = self.context['request'].FILES
        post = Post.objects.create(**validated_data)

        for image_data in images_data.getlist('image') :
           Image.objects.create(post=post, image=image_data)
        return post
```

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.conf import settings

class Post (models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='author', null=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    text = models.TextField(max_length=300)
    tag = models.CharField(max_length=511, null=True)
    view = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    viewer = models.ManyToManyField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, related_name='viewer', blank=True)
    like = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    liker = models.ManyToManyField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, related_name='liker', blank=True)

    def __str__ (self) :
        return self.title

class Image (models.Model) :
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    image = models.ImageField(null=True, blank=True)

class Comment (models.Model) :
    author = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    text = models.TextField(max_length=200)
```

Comment: I suspect that your data dump in data.json has a byte order mark. Can you check the encoding used?

Comment: Use encoding `utf-8-sig` instead of `utf-8` where possible to specify it.

Comment: @Arty Where can I change it?

Comment: @leedjango Your current code doesn't contains request decoding, so somwhere in other code.

Comment: @leedjango Please post other code, especially one that decode input, we'll find a bug.

Comment: @Arty Thanks! I add it